# Composition Method for negative term

Tags: probability, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, sampling, simulation

I'm a undergraduate student now learning a graduate simulation course, and I met some problems.
The Professor ask us to sample this function by composition method. Its CDF and PDF are like:
$$
F(x)=1-e^{-x}-e^{-2x}+e^{-3x} \\
f(x)=-3e^{-3x}+2e^{-2x} +e^{-x}
$$
I found out the PDF has a negative term $-3x$, and I don't know how to deal with it.
P.S. The Professor taught us the examples but there're all positive terms.

thx btw.

Comment: What is the range of $X$? I assume $0 < X < \infty$.

Comment: Maybe just rewrite your density as $f(x) = (e^{-x} - e^{-3x}) + 2(e^{-2x} - e^{-3x})$ and take it from there?

Comment: @Aruralreader Yes, the range is $0 < X$. I've tried to rewrite to $F(x) = (1+e^{-x})*(1+e^({-2x})$ before, and have no idea. I'll try your way later. thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your density as $(e^{-x} - e^{-3x}) + 2(e^{-2x} - e^{-3x})$. Neither $e^{-x} - e^{-3x}$ nor $e^{-2x} - e^{-3x}$ are proper densities, but you can check that
\begin{align}
f_1(x) &= \tfrac{3}{2}(e^{-x} - e^{-3x}),\\
f_2(x) &= 6(e^{-2x} - e^{-3x})
\end{align}
are. That means you can write your $f$ as
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \tfrac{2}{3}f_1(x) + (2)(\tfrac{1}{6})f_2(x) \\
&= \tfrac{2}{3}f_1(x) + \tfrac{1}{3}f_2(x).
\end{align*}
So one possible composition method is:

- Generate $U$ uniformly from $[0, 1]$.
- If $U \leq \tfrac{2}{3}$ generate a variate from $f_1$; otherwise from $f_2$.

The latter step is easy since you can use sums of two exponentially distributed variates. Generate $E$ and $E'$ as independent exponentially distributed, each with mean 1. If you need an $f_1$ return $E + \tfrac{1}{3}E'$. Otherwise $\tfrac{1}{2}E + \tfrac{1}{3}E'$ gives you an $f_2$.

Comment: Thank you very much . You're awesome !